# Can't play audio in Android device

Tags: android, audio, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to make something like this :

```
    <audio controls>
    <source src="media/blablabla.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
```

I run my app on local host :8080/console and it worked (The music can played). But when I run that apps on my device, the music can't played.

My Device OS is Android 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

See this question for an answer: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unable to play a local media file using Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057260/ibm-worklight-6-1-unable-to-play-a-local-media-file-using-cordova)

Copy-paste of my answer:

> ... for playing a local media file, you need to provide the full path
>   to the media file's location *where it'll be in the generated Android
>   project*. For example, if you create a `common\audio` folder in the
>   Worklight application and place a .mp3 file in it, you need to use the
>   following path (in the HTML or JavaScript, or however you'd like...):
>
> ```
> <a href="#" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/default/audio/myMediaFile.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
> ```
>
> Sample project: [Android Cordova Media API](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s486qgir28zst4i/AndroidCordovaMediaAPI.zip)

Comment: I have tried Playing audio via phonegap and cordova for Android but it still not worked in android (worklight), can you give an example in worklight ?