# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Unable to play a local media file using Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Tested in Android Emulator.

I am trying to use Cordova Media API to manage the playing of audio stored locally within the Worklight project. Initially I attempted to update my project to accomplish this task, but was not successful, so I decide to use the complete example documented on the Apache Cordova Media API page. I used the full sample to play, pause, and stop an audio file. The only change I made was to play the audio file stored locally in my worklight project.

However, the above fails...

I created a new folder, "WavAudo", in the sample project that contains .mp3, and .wav versions of the audio to play.

When I start the application I receive an alert popup that the `error.code`, and `error.message` are `undefined`. Using Chrome debugger I see the that on `deviceready` I get `Uncaught ReferenceError Media is not defined`.

I beleive I've tried all possible path+file combinations to locate the file, but I must have missed something.

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Media Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        playAudio("/android_asset/www/WavAudio/16300.mp3");
    }

    // Audio player
    //
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    //
    function playAudio(src) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

        // Play audio
        my_media.play();

        // Update my_media position every second
        if (mediaTimer == null) {
            mediaTimer = setInterval(function() {
                // get my_media position
                my_media.getCurrentPosition(
                    // success callback
                    function(position) {
                        if (position > -1) {
                            setAudioPosition((position) + " sec");
                        }
                    },
                    // error callback
                    function(e) {
                        console.log("Error getting pos=" + e);
                        setAudioPosition("Error: " + e);
                    }
                );
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

    // Pause audio
    //
    function pauseAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    //
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    //
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    //
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    // Set audio position
    //
    function setAudioPosition(position) {
        document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="playAudio
    ('/android_asset/www/WavAudio/16300.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="pauseAudio();">Pause Playing Audio</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn large" onclick="stopAudio();">Stop Playing Audio</a>
    <p id="audio_position"></p>
  </body>
```

I also added these to Android Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Can you go to your `app_folder\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml` and see if the media plugin is correctly defined, e.g: `<feature name="Media">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code provided at Cordova's website works, however it looks like the URL they point to is  broken. I've [replaced it with another](http://www.tonycuffe.com/mp3/tail%20toddle.mp3) and then it worked.

As for playing a local media file, you need to provide the full path to the media file's location *where it'll be in the generated Android project*. For example, if you create a `common\audio` folder in the Worklight application and place a .mp3 file in it, you need to use the following path (in the HTML or JavaScript, or however you'd like...):

```
<a href="#" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/default/audio/myMediaFile.mp3');">Play Audio</a>
```

This is because in Worklight, every application is considered a "skin". There is the "default" skin, and [if you add another](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/05_03_Supporting_multiple_form_factors_using_Worklight_skins.pdf), it will have its own folder in the `www` folder.

Sample project: [Android Cordova Media API](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s486qgir28zst4i/AndroidCordovaMediaAPI.zip)

---

P.S., I do not find it a good practice to copy-paste an example as-is from Cordova to a Worklight project.

- There is no cordova.js to link to.
- It is redundant to listen to `deviceready` as this is handled internally. Putting it this way: if you've reached `wlCommonInit()`, you're good to go.
- There is no need to add extra permissions, unless you want what those permissions offer...

Comment: I've applied all advice provided to find success.  1)Removed cordova.js script def 2)Removed the device ready event listener setup.  As a last bit of hope I renamed my audio folder under common to "audio"  I used the path suggested above to my file. /android_asset/www/default/audio/16300.mp3  I build, then use Chrome to test Android.  When I click play I get the alert pop-up on "my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);" The pop-up has code:undefined and message:undefined. I've recreated this sample in new workspace with no luck. Appreciate all ideas. I'll continue searching here. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot test this via Worklight Console. You must test in either Android Emulator or Device. What do you mean "chrome"?

Comment: I have the Android sdk & AVD manager installed along with my Worklight. In my project I have common, and Android env created. I build all env's and deploy to the Worklight Dev Server. (internal).  I use Chrome to point at the Dev Server  http://localhost:10080/PlayTime/console/#catalog I click the Android preview eye for my app that starts the Android emulator showing my default device "Kindle Fire II"  I select the play audio button and I get the pop-up with both fields error, and msg "Undefined".  Please let me know if my build/test process is flawed.  Thank You.

Comment: This is exactly what I just told you - you CANNOT use the Worklight Console's MBS to hear the audio file using android_asset, because this file is saved in the NATIVE folder of your application, whereas the MBS only previews you WEB RESOURCES. Next time, please don't use the word "emulator", this implies you're testing on the actual Android Emulator, which you are not doing. Try my sample project; run it on an actual Android device or the Android Emulator. Then, it will work.

Comment: Idan, Thank You very much.  I apologize for mis-using the terminology.  I deployed, and ran on the Andriod Emulator, and I do hear the audio play now. Misunderstanding on my part the audio would not be available in the console MBS. Appreciate your time, patience, and advice.