# how to preview the Capture Audio file in application

Tags: cordova, voice

how to do preview and play the captured voice recording file(audio file) in application. any one please have the sample code or project provide link or code.

```js
function captureAudio() {
    // Launch device audio recorder
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError);
 }

var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        // do something interesting with the file
        name = mediaFile.name;
    }
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

// start audio capture
navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:2});
```

```html
<a href="#" data-role="button" id="button0" onclick="captureAudio()">Button</a>
```

Comment: this does not relate to mobilefirst or its studio. It has anything to do with Cordova. Cordova is bundled in MobileFirst. Look at the Cordova APIs how to accomplish this.

Comment: oky, i am recording the voice and storing in local storage but i am not able to preview that file

Comment: When you are previewing an app, you are previewing only the web resources, not the app. That's why it is not available.

Comment: i am capture the audio file but i am not able to preview and play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function captureAudio() {
    navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError);
 }

function playMP3() {
    media.play();
}

function captureError(e) {
    console.log("capture error: "+JSON.stringify(e));
}

function captureSuccess(s) {
    console.log("Success");
    var a="<audio controls>"
     a += "<source src='" + s[0].fullPath + "' type='video/mp4'>";
    a += "</audio>";
    document.querySelector("#audioArea").innerHTML = a;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page" id="page">
       <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
     <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="captureAudio()">audio</a> 
     <div id="audioArea" onclick="playMP3()"></div>
    </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play an mp3 file that you have downloaded by following the instructions provided in these questions:

- [How to handle files using Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326618/how-to-handle-files-using-cordova)
- [How to delete a file using Cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326609/how-to-delete-a-file-using-cordova/33326610)
- [Can't play audio in Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774559/cant-play-audio-in-android-device)

Comment: what ever i capture the audio file i am not able to preview Idan, after preview i want play that file. first i need to how to preview the capture audio file

Comment: The code provided in the links above teaches you have to download & play a file in a Cordova **mobile application** (in the device. I don't know what you're talking about when saying "preview"). You need to do some work now and refactor it to fit your own requirements.